# Read a file line by line and assign two lines at the same loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .txt file having more than 1,000 rows, which likes this:

```
Y1
Y2
Y3
...
```

I want to read them in a script and generate a Makefile.
I think I should use loop for this, which could get:

```
$file_Y2(as a target): $file_Y1(as a prerequisites)
command
$file_Y3(as a target): $file_Y2(as a prerequisites)
command
...
```

but in a loop using `read -r line`, I can do stuff like assign Y1 (which will be `$line`) to `$file_Y1`, but did not know how to assign `Y2` to `$file_Y2`(which is the next line) in the same loop.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal input with an exact output you need? Your current information is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the file in an array and then just iterate through the array.

```
mapfile -t -O1 lines < file
for ((i=1;i<${#lines[@]};i++));do
    echo "target file ${lines[i+1]} - depends on ${lines[i]}"
done
```

Comment: You are missing the closing brace after `${lines[i+1]`.  Also you probably want to stop at `${#lines[@]}-1` so that the last line makes sense.

Comment: @GrishaLevit Thanks. Now should be ok with -O option of mapfile

Comment: I think it's what I want and very elegant, thanks a lot

Comment: @Forrestchen Welcome. If you are happy with this answer you can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about following sample?

```
awk '{ar[NR]=$0} END {for (i in ar) {if (i>1) {{print "$file_"ar[i]"(as a target): $file_"ar[i-1]"(as a prerequisites)"}{print "command"}}}}' file.txt
```

Input:

```
Y1
Y2
Y3
Y4
```

Output:

```
$file_Y2(as a target): $file_Y1(as a prerequisites)
command
$file_Y3(as a target): $file_Y2(as a prerequisites)
command
$file_Y4(as a target): $file_Y3(as a prerequisites)
command
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
skip=yes
while read line; do
  if [ $skip = yes ]; then 
    oldline=$line
  else 
    echo "\$file_$line(as target): \$file_$oldline(as prerequisite)"
    oldline=$line
  fi
  skip=no
done < tmp.txt
```

From your input, output is:

```
$file_Y2(as target): $file_Y1(as prerequisite)
$file_Y3(as target): $file_Y2(as prerequisite)
$file_Y4(as target): $file_Y3(as prerequisite)
```

The trick, as I understand, is that you need *two* lines of input to generate a new line of output. Therefore, you need two variables - a line from input, kept in $line, and another line, kept in $oldline. In your case it happens that you need a line, and *the previous one*, so $oldline simply remembers the previous one. Nothing prevents you to do something else, and even add "*some commands*" after every line generated.

Comment: thanks, I think it's a very detailed and useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to duplicate a large part of your input. With `paste` you can combine the corresponding lines of two files. With `<()` you can make the output of a command act as an input file, so we can use `sed` to delete the first or last line:

```
paste <(sed '1d' input.txt) <(sed '$d' input.txt)
```

Now you want to use the `paste` output for writing the lines.

```
printf "\$file_%s(as a target): \$file_%s(as a prerequisites)\ncommand\n" \
   $(paste <(sed '1d' input.txt) <(sed '$d' input.txt))
```

(Note that you shouldn't have a space or tab after the `\` at the end of the first line.)